# Changing AC Fan Motor/Capacitor with No Luck

Tags: hvac, thermostat, central-air

Issues with a central AC unit:

Turned it on and heard a buzzing sound, but the fan didn't start.

Started by looking at the dual capacitor. We happen to have two identical units, so I tried the capacitor on the second unit and it ran fine, so crossed that one off.

Ordered a new fan motor, which came with it's own single run capacitor.

This morning I hooked up the new 3-wire motor and new capacitor:

- Black to line
- Jumper from Common on the dual capacitor and purple to one terminal
- Brown to the other

Didn't hook it up to the fan blade, because that sucker is rusted onto the old fan and good.

Turned on the AC, and the fan motor didn't do a thing. Still a humming sound. Electricity detector showed that all lines had juice flowing through them.

Nothing from the new motor.

I switched out my thermostat for an Ecobee in the winter, but when tested initially it seemed to work. And when jumped we got the same buzzing from the AC unit.

Any thoughts of what to do next?

Pretty frustrated.

[image: Run capacitors]

[image: Run capacitor, single]

[image: Connections to electric]

[image: Fan motor]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's the make and model of the central A/C? (And, a picture or two would be helpful.)

Comment: Hi and thanks. It’s a Goodman CKL24-1h.  I’ll add some photos when I get back home. I assume you want to see the capacitor wiring?

Comment: Here are some pics!  
https://photos.app.goo.gl/ePQwrsTLCeFGr6Q29

Comment: add the pictures to the question

Comment: what is `Electricity detector`?

Comment: Just a voltage detector pen. Keeps folks like me safe :) Pics added to the post. Thanks very much, all.